# self-sizing collectionview auto set contentoffset zero

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I use UICollectionView flowlayout self-sizing show two textview for input.
when user input, i invalidate layout

```
UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext *context =
[[UICollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext alloc] init];
[context invalidateItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
context.contentSizeAdjustment = CGSizeMake(0, newHeight - oldHeight);
[self.flowlayout invalidateLayoutWithContext:context];
```

but then collectionview call layoutSubViews, set contentSize many times, because contentSize too small, so it call setContentOffsetIfNeed, then offset be zero.
I need offset keep original value. see below call stack:
[image]

anybody know why and resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `[self.context sizeToFit]` To self-sizing it

Comment: I do not found UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext have sizeToFit method neither UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes